# IE Button Click not working using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ie-automation

I'm trying to automate the click of a button in an one of my company's websites. I have tired clicking it using an object or a HTMLelement but none of them worked. Any suggestions? Below is the HTML code of the button

`<div class="gw-ToolbarButtonWidget gw-styleTag--ToolbarWidget gw-putSubMenusBelow gw-isTopLevelMenu gw-hasMinimizedView gw-action--outer" id="InitManualRenewalPage-NewManualConvertRenewal" aria-disabled="false"><div tabindex="0" class="gw-action--inner gw-hasDivider" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Next >" data-gw-click="fireEvent id:^" data-gw-confirm="Are you sure you want to start a manual renewal transaction?"><div class="gw-minimized-view"><div class="gw-label-min gw-min-visible" data-gw-tooltip="Next >" data-gw-mouseenter="gwMouse.enter" data-gw-mousemove="gwTooltips.move" data-gw-mouseout="gwTooltips.hide" data-gw-mouseover-enabled="true" data-gw-mouseout-enabled="true" data-gw-mousemove-enabled="true" data-gw-mouseenter-enabled="true">Ne</div></div><div class="gw-label" aria-hidden="true">Next &gt;</div></div></div>`

Comment: If you want to do browser automation using VBA I recommend you take a look at [selenium basic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoxWcvZzYVk&ab_channel=WiseOwlTutorials).

Comment: @GWD Unfortunately, I couldn't use this as an option as my company's firewall prevents my ability to download the necessary drivers, etc needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only element that looks "button" like in your code is the `<div>` with `role=button`.

The following (if you add the references, and substitute the URL) will click what I beleive is the button.

```
' Required Referece (VBA IDE->Tools->References...)
' > Microsoft Internet Controls
' > Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub Main()
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim Button As IHTMLElement

Browser.Navigate "http://127.0.0.1/example.html"

Do Until Browser.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set Document = Browser.Document

If Document Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error, Failed to get Document"
    Exit Sub
End If
' 
Set Button = Document.getElementById("InitManualRenewalPage-NewManualConvertRenewal")

If Button Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error, Failed to get Button (container)"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Button = Button.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)

If Button Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error, Failed to get Button (actual)"
    Exit Sub
End If

Button.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this before and tried it again after your suggestion and it unfortunately did not work.