# vba web scrapping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been able to launch the website and input the value but I'm not able to press enter to get the output value. It's an online calculator that allows you to see the temperature of a refrigerant while inputting a pressure. the output(temperature) is supposed to change when you input(pressure), however when I do it the output(temperature) stays the same while I'm able to change the input(pressure). could you tell me what might be the reason for this? is the website blocking my input? i get this error: (run-time erro91: object variable or with block variable not set)

when i run the code for this code "ht.getElementById("pressure").Value = "20""

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmh5.png)

here is my code:

```
Sub test()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument
Dim temp As Object
Dim press As Object


Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("https://reftools.danfoss.com/spa/tools/ref-slider#/")



Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       DoEvents
 Loop


Set ht = ie.document

'input
ht.getElementById("pressure").Value = "20"



'Set temp = ht.getElementsByClassName("temperature")
'Set press = ht.getElementsByClassName("pressure")

'i = 1
'For Each te In temp
   'Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = te.innerText
   'i = i + 1
'Next































End Sub
```

Comment: Is `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` defined? Also does the error point to `ht.get...` or `set HT = document`

Comment: Not an answer, but shows how to check that the things your referencing exist before trying to use them https://stackoverflow.com/a/74160150/212869

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

There is an API you can call to perform the same conversion. Below is an example implementation of calling that API using a custom function which accepts the pressure as input and returns the temperature in Celsius.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetTempFromPressure(ByVal pressure As Double) As Double
    Dim body As String
  
    body = "{""pressure"":""" & pressure & """,""refId"":""r404a"",""temperatureUnit"":""celsius"",""pressureUnit"":""bar"","
    body = body & """pressureReferencePoint"":""absolute"","
    body = body & """pressureCalculationPoint"":""dew"",""gaugeType"":""dry"",""altitudeInMeter"":0}"
       
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://reftools.danfoss.com/api/ref-slider/temperature?refId=r404a", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        .send body
        GetTempFromPressure = CDbl(.responseText)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub test()

    MsgBox GetTempFromPressure(20)
    
End Sub
```